# Generalized rule behind equating real and imaginary components

Tags: vector-spaces

When two complex numbers $z$ and $w$ are said to be equal, that implies that

Re$(z)$=Re$(w)$

and that

Im$(z)$=Im$(w)$.

I believe this, and always have, but now I wonder what the generalized rule is behind it. I know that if $z$ and $w$ were two-dimensional vectors, one could appeal to the linear independence of their two components. But I know that the set of complex numbers forms a field, not a vector space (correct?) so what would be the appropriate statement in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As well as being a field in its own right, $\Bbb{C}$ is a two-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb{R}$ with scalar $\times$ vector multiplication given by restricting complex multiplication to $\Bbb{R} \times \Bbb{C}$.  $1$ and $i$ are a basis, leading to the rule about equating real and imaginary parts.